# Getting the latest date from a subquery (with more than 1 record) in the Insert Statement

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table I need to copy my data from (Log), into another table (BigTable). The Log table got the following data:

```
   LogID   LogTime             JobNumber    LogType   Description
   =====   =======             =========    =======   ===========
   1       2012-09-01 00:00:01   1          100       Accepted by D#12
   2       2012-09-01 00:05:33   1          100       Accepted by D#14
   3       2012-09-01 01:00:14   2          107       Message sent
   4       2012-09-01 05:00:53   2          100       Accepted by D#78
   5       2012-09-01 05:01:55   1          110       POB at Stop 1
   6       2012-09-01 05:02:22   3          100       Accepted by D#98
   7       2012-09-01 05:03:00   1          110       POB at Stop 2
   8       2012-09-01 05:04:00   2          110       POB at Stop 1
   9       2012-09-01 05:05:25   3          110       POB at Stop 1
  10       2012-09-01 05:15:36   1          200       Completed
  11       2012-09-01 05:20:45   2          200       Completed
```

The following data is already in BigTable

```
   JobNumber     Accepted_At     POB_At       Completed
   =========     ===========     ======       =========
    1            NULL            NULL         NULL
    2            NULL            NULL         NULL
    3            NULL            NULL         NULL
```

I am trying to update BigTable with values from Log. Note that in case of duplicate entries like LogID 1 and 2 (above), I am picking up only the latest date (2012-09-01 00:05:33). The same is desired for POB, as we are only interested in "POB at Stop 1".

There are millions of rows in Log for lots of Job numbers, however, I need to get time for only those Jobs which are in BigTable only.
The Ideal table (after all updates) will look like the following:

```
   JobNumber   Accepted_At            POB_At                  Completed
   =========   ===========            ======                  =========
    1          2012-09-01 00:05:33    2012-09-01 05:01:55     2012-09-01 05:15:36
    2          2012-09-01 05:00:53    2012-09-01 05:04:00     2012-09-01 05:20:45
    3          2012-09-01 05:02:22    2012-09-01 05:05:25     NULL
```

Please note I am novice in this field. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
Regards

Comment: +1 for sample data and desired output.

Comment: Why is the row where LogID = 7 ignored? Because the description is "POB at Stop 2"? If there were only two rows for a job and this was one of them, would it still be ignored?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, Yes, we are just looking for "POB at Stop 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could aggregate the MAX dates in a CTE and then join it to BigTable for the update:

```
; WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
    g.JobNumber
    , Accepted_At = MAX(CASE WHEN LogType = 100 THEN LogTime END)
    , POB_At = MAX(CASE WHEN LogType = 110 AND [Description] LIKE '%Stop%1' THEN LogTime END)
    , Completed = MAX(CASE WHEN LogType = 200 THEN LogTime END)
    FROM [Log] g
    GROUP BY g.JobNumber, g.LogType
)
UPDATE b
SET Accepted_At = CTE.Accepted_At
, POB_At = CTE.POB_At
, Completed = CTE.Completed
FROM CTE
JOIN BigTable b ON b.JobNumber = CTE.JobNumber
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, please don't get me wrong, but I've already explained my skill level (nothing). what is CTE?
Kind regards

Comment: Common Table Expression. Really just a special type of subquery that's being used here in lieu of a temp table.

Comment: Well thanks a lot man, i just googled it and now this query works. Great, Thank you again. regards

Answer (score 0):

This will work since you are using mssql server 2008

```
merge bigtable t1
using 
(select jobnumber, 
min(case when description like 'Accepted by%' then logtime end) 
Accepted_At, min(case when description like 'POB at%' then logtime end) POB_At, 
min(case when description like 'Completed' then logtime end) Completed 
from <table> group by jobnumber) t2
on t1.jobunmber = t2.jobnumber
-- the 2 next lines are optional, but they could help in 
-- situations where jobnumber is not already in the bigtable
when not matched then INSERT t1(JobNumber, Accepted_At, POB_At, Completed )   
values (t2.JobNumber, t2.Accepted_At, t2.POB_At, t2.Completed)
when matched then 
update
set t1.Accepted_At = t2.Accepted_At,
t1.POB_At = t2.POB_At
t1.Completed = t2.Completed;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please note:

It is giving me an error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'update'."

when matched then 
update t1

Regards

Comment: @user1001493 I had not tested my script, it is corrected now for what it is worth